# Red5 : How can i get event when recording finished?

Tags: java, video-streaming, red5, red5-recorder, red5pro

Red5 masters.
I'm implementing a red5 recording system and I need to record the start time and end time.
I need to know the how to register the point when record finishes in red5 on the server side.

How can I archive it?

Comment: Please include the lines of code related to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A recording stop and the end of publishing would essentially be the same on the server since you cannot stop recording directly. A good way to catch this "event" is to override the `streamBroadcastClose` method in your `ApplicationAdapter`; the parent method itself is here: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/blob/eda471d3a005adb2555ca2d59e18844825f813c4/src/main/java/org/red5/server/adapter/MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter.java#L1202